# Проблема при запуске проекта на eclips

Tags: java

Здравстуйте товарищи   кодеры,у меня проблема  при запуске  проекта на эклипсе  (код написан без ошибок) вот сам скрин ошибки при запуске [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: товарищ кодер, может java, а не javascript?

Comment: я просто не нашел  java    там

Comment: Не знаю, с чем это связано, ни разу не видел такого, но я бы первым делом проверил, правильно ли у `eclipse` настроен путь к `JDK` (Preferences/Java/Installed JRE). Судя по сообщению, `eclipse` не может соединиться с отладчиком.